# Ubuntu terminal: strange symbols instead of my username

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, rvm

I have a strange problem with my Ubuntu terminal: when I open it instead of seeing my username I see this:

```
32m]u@h[033[00m]:[033[01: command not found
31m]w[033[00m]$: command not found
’[033[01
```

Strangely enough bash commands work normally, the terminal just does not show my username or the current path. I googled, but was unable to find any answers. The most recent changes I made on my computer involved installing RVM (Ruby Version Manager) and manually editing the PATH to add RVM in files: .bash_profile, .profile and .bashrc, but after that it all worked normally, so I am not really sure that could be the reason.

Comment: It looks like your prompt is not correctly set-up. You should probably ask about this on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've edited the PS1 variable by mistake when modifying the `~/.bashrc`, which controls the prompt layout. You'll need to edit your `~/.bashrc` and replace it with the following default.

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

For more information on other changes you can make to your prompt have a look at [Customising Bash Prompt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt). The change wouldn't appear immediately after modifying the file because `bash` doesn't reload it's configuration once you've changed the file automatically. You'll either need to exit the shell and start a new one or reload the configuration using

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

The `.` at the begining is needed, it's shorthand for the `source` command.